# Determining the timespan to the previous record with the same ID

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a table with multiple occurrence of the same animal ID on different dates.

```
tableA
+-----------+------------+
| animalid  |  calvdate  |
+-----------+------------+
| A         | 2018-08-30 |
| B         | 2018-08-30 |
| A         | 2018-09-10 |
| C         | 2018-08-30 |
| A         | 2019-08-30 |
+-----------+------------+
```

I want to create a table that calculates number of days since the last recorded date of an animal

```
expected output
+-----------+------------+--------------+
|  animalid |  calvdate  | NumberOfDays |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| A         | 2018-08-30 |            0 |
| A         | 2018-09-10 |           11 |
| A         | 2019-08-30 |          355 |
| B         | 2018-08-30 |            0 |
| C         | 2018-08-30 |            0 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

I have tried using the following query:

```
SELECT
  animalid,
  calvdate, TO_DAYS(x.calvdate)-TO_DAYS(calvdate) AS NumberOfDays, 
  (SELECT calvdate FROM tableA as x WHERE animalid = animalid ORDER BY asc)
FROM
  tableA
```

How can I generate my expected output?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33,

Comment: Window functions of 8.0 would make this significantly easier if you have a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It `LEFT JOIN`s the original table to itself, where the `calvdate` in the second table is the maximum `calvdate` less than that in the first. Then we take the difference of those two dates to get the length of time, using `COALESCE` to deal with there being no matching row in the second table:

```
SELECT a.animalid, a.calvdate, 
       COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, b.calvdate, a.calvdate), 0) AS NumberOfDays
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableA b ON b.animalid = a.animalid AND
                      b.calvdate = (SELECT MAX(calvdate) 
                                    FROM tableA a2 
                                    WHERE a2.calvdate < a.calvdate 
                                      AND a2.animalid = a.animalid)
ORDER BY a.animalid
```

Output:

```
animalid    calvdate    NumberOfDays
A           2018-08-30  0
A           2018-09-10  11
A           2019-08-30  354
B           2018-08-30  0
C           2018-08-30  0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQ3hzi9VtoiLWiqRd83Vho/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT tableA.animalid,tableA.calvdate,TO_DAYS(tableA.calvdate)-TO_DAYS(x.calvdate) AS NumberOfDays 
    FROM tableA 
    inner join (
        SELECT MIN(calvdate), animalid FROM tableA GROUP BY animalid)
    ) x ON tableA.animalid = x.animalid
```

It uses to get minimum date for all animals in the sub query as join and use it for subtraction to find NumberOfDays field.